# Where and how to host our web app for high performance and availability

Tags: scalability, web-hosting, cloud-hosting, memory-bandwidth

I have been working an application using PHP & MySql on Codeigniter framework. It is finished and I am testing it before getting online. I expect about a hundred users within the next few months. I expect increasing number of users for the application who will be using it on daily basis. My issue is high availability, fast service and database size.

Could someone please provide a link where I can get answers to questions such as:

After how many users will the application get heavy? Should I buy a normal web hosting plan or a dedicated server? What should be the configuration of the server and the connection? Will cloud hosting be better anyway? How about increasing size of my database?

Warm Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can start with a shared/cloud hosting in the initial stage untill you face high traffic. Then depends on the traffic stats you can decide whether you can go with a vps or a dedicated server. I think the upgradation to a vps or a dedicated server will not affect your website downtime.

Comment: I think you are right and I should start with shared/cloud and see what happens with time.